# Query Min, Max and associated columns data from the same rows

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, postgresql-9.4, greatest-n-per-group

I have query in which returns averaged values by site and month.  What I want to know is the min and max of those monthly averages by site and (the difficult part) the month when each occurred.

Here is an example:

[SQL Fiddle Stuff here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6cb1f)

```
CREATE TABLE events (
    esite     integer NOT NULL,
    edate     timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    evalue    integer NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO events Values
    (1, '2016-01-03', 11),
    (2, '2016-01-05', 90),
    (1, '2016-01-08', 7),
    (2, '2016-01-10', 40),
    (1, '2016-01-15', 12),
    (1, '2016-01-18', 66),
    (2, '2016-01-22', 54),
    (2, '2016-02-03', 70),
    (2, '2016-02-05', 56),
    (1, '2016-02-08', 61),
    (2, '2016-02-10', 23),
    (1, '2016-02-15', 30),
    (1, '2016-02-18', 15),
    (1, '2016-02-22', 41);
```

I'm looking for a query that returns (by site) the min and max monthly average `evalue` and the months at which the min and max values occurred. I can get this by using the query below:

[SQL Fiddle this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6cb1f/6)

```
select esite, date_trunc('month', edate) as emonth, round(avg(evalue),2) as evalue_avg from events
  Group by esite, emonth
```

Produces the following output:

```
esite | emonth                      | evalue_avg
2     | January, 01 2016 00:00:00   | 61.33
1     | January, 01 2016 00:00:00   | 24
1     | February, 01 2016 00:00:00  | 36.75
2     | February, 01 2016 00:00:00  | 49.67
```

Now for the part I'm having difficultly with, I need produce the following result - basically the min, max values and the date(month) at which each occurred by site.
Desired Output:

```
-- (one row per site)
esite | avg_min | eval_avg_min_date          | avg_max | eval_avg_max
1     | 24.00   | January, 01 2016 00:00:00  | 36.75   | February, 01 2016 00:00:00
2     | 49.67   |February, 01 2016 00:00:00  | 61.33   | January, 01 2016 00:00:00
```

I've searched around and have seen some examples using windowing and lateral joins, but I haven't been successful in getting any of them to work.  This might be a pivot but since I don't have a fixed number of sites, this tends to be difficult with PostgreSQL.

I'm guessing if anyone has an easy way to do this using Postgres 9.4+.

Comment: Something like "select min(avg_value), max(avg_value), month from _grp group by month"? Note: not tested.

Comment: @Verace.  I'm looking for a little more than that and I've updated the question to hopefully communicate it better. :)

Answer (score 2):

<sub>The question is old, but the CommunityBot keeps bumping it. Let's add a proper answer.</sub>

Move your avg calculation into a CTE, and use the results in two joined `DISTINCT ON` queries:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT esite, date_trunc('month', edate) AS emonth, round(avg(evalue), 2) AS evalue_avg
   FROM   events
   GROUP  BY esite, emonth
   )
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (esite) 
          esite, evalue_avg, emonth
   FROM   cte
   ORDER  BY esite, evalue_avg, emonth
   ) a
JOIN  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (esite) 
          esite, evalue_avg, emonth
   FROM   cte
   ORDER  BY esite, evalue_avg DESC, emonth
   ) z USING (esite);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=94418d4a2c3d4c216782986b250ee3ae)*

(Would even work in the outdated Postgres 9.4.)

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)
- [Get values from first and last row per group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25173081/939860)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you do something like this - and don't go down the route of having a row per month.

What happens when you have 5 (10...15... x) years' data?

This is superior IMHO. You can always use the `CROSSTAB` table function, but I would recommend against it.

```
SELECT
  esite,
  MIN(evalue), 
  MAX(evalue),
  AVG(evalue)::INT,
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM edate) AS emonth,
  CASE
    WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM edate) = 1 THEN 'January'
    WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM edate) = 2 THEN 'February'
    -- <... fill in rest of months here ...>
  END AS litMonth
FROM events
GROUP BY esite, emonth, litMonth
ORDER BY esite, emonth -- , min, max, avg;
```

This gives the result:

```
esite;     min;   max;   avg;    emonth;    litmonth
----------------------------------------------------
    1;       7;    66;    24;     1;         January
    1;      15;    61;    37;     2;        February
    2;      40;    90;    61;     1;         January
    2;      23;    70;    50;     2;        February
```

Note, that I have `CAST` the AVG as an `INTEGER` - you can of course `ROUND` this off to whatever you like. You can add `EXTRACT(YEAR  FROM edate) AS eyear,` after the `EXTRACT(MONTH...` for more clarity and a more elegant result.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but its still not quiet what I'm looking for.  I'm looking for the min and max of the monthly averages (which are already calculated by the first query) and then getting the date of when those min and max values occurred (still within the aggregate result).  So my issue is how to get the first query into my desired output and not necessarily with the date formatting.

Comment: Suppose two/three/..n minima/maxima are the same for a given esite for a given month?